# db2 V10.5 Enabling parallelism steps

Tags: database, db2, db2-luw

I have enabled intra_parallel parameter to yes.

And update DFT_DEGREE parameter to 8 (8 processor is on server with 1 core each).

Now I am confuse about parameter MAX_QUERYDEGREE parameter.

Should I update the parameter to 8 or not? Currently its 1.

Comment: Make sure that you understand what you are trying to solve here. The database engine is multithreaded, and even without enabling `intra_parallel` you will find that DB2 will be able to use multiple CPU cores with just a single query in process.  Database engine threads (such as I/O servers [fetching data from disk to bufferpools], I/O cleaners [writing dirty pages from buffer pool to disk], logger, etc) will all run in parallel with the agent process servicing your query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DFT_DEGREE specifies the value used for the CURRENT DEGREE special register.  The Maximum Query Degree of Parallelism (MAX_QUERYDEGREE) configuration parameter specifies the maximum query degree of intrapartition parallelism for all SQL queries.
The default for MAX_QUERYDEGREE is -1 which means ANY.  This lets the optimizer decide what the max parallelism will be for a query which start at the DFT_DEGREE value.